# On earth, is a levelled ground perpendicular to the radius of earth?

Tags: topology, geometry

During construction of a building we level the ground using laser or more simply a water pipe.

Method using water pipe:  We level the ground such that  the water level is same at all four corners of the rectangular ground.

Does this method result in a rectangular plane that is perpendicular to the radius of the earth?

[image]

Comment: Search term: “geoid”.

Comment: Note that you should get different results using a laser and using a water pipe....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazingly, no, it would follow the curvature of the earth, but the error would be tiny.  On this scale, the earth **is** flat.  The laser sight build would be slightly shorter in the middle.

With something on the scale of a suspension bridge it would matter, the floor of your garage, not so much.

Comment: Oh so if I have an earth sized rectangular water prism, the water surface in the prism will be curved like the curve of the earth?

Comment: Well, the Pacific Ocean seems to be.

Comment: Yes but it has a curved base too... if it were to have a rectangular base with side walls, then also will the surface of water  curve?

Comment: If you laser sighted your base, at some point the two ends would be significantly above the earths surface.  If you filled it with water, the water would level with the base.  On a macro scale it gets interesting, but again, who would build a suspension bridge size or many times larger that way? A laser base 4000 miles long ... hmm.

Comment: $90 degrees/6000 miles = 0.015$ degrees per mile.  "And I will walk 500 miles and I will walk 500 more ..."